# How to speed up queries in sqlite android in db.execSql

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have the following code that I use to enter data in the database.

```
public static void execSql(SQLiteDatabase db, String sql)
{
    String[] parts = sql.split(";");
    for (String entry : parts) {
        db.execSQL(entry);
    }   
}
```

Initially all "INSERT ......" in sql string, then execute each insert cycle. Total insert are 22908. Data is input for about 4 minutes, which I think is a long time. Data is 7,95 MB. Is there any way to speed up the introduction and bring it to seconds ?

```
INSERT INTO location ( 'latitude' , 'updated' , 'id' , 'longitude' , 'created' ) VALUES( '213.2000000' , '2014-08-25 11:07:42+00:00' , '1' , '321.0000000' , '2014-08-25 11:07:42+00:00' );
INSERT INTO location ( 'latitude' , 'updated' , 'id' , 'longitude' , 'created' ) VALUES( '42.7191000' , '2014-09-17 12:53:49+00:00' , '2' , '23.0834000' , '2014-09-17 12:53:49+00:00' );
......................
```

Here are the data sql variable.

Comment: Use Prepared Statements (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the work in a transaction:

```
db.beginTransaction();

try {
  // your SQL goes here
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Right now, you are doing one transaction per SQL statement, which is horribly slow. Each transaction involves disk I/O, and it is much more efficient to do one larger batch of disk I/O than thousands of little ones.

Using prepared statements will incrementally help as well.

Comment: Thank you very definitely hurried and already running in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the same query with only different parameter values . That's why you can take advantage of precompiled sql statements. You can create object of [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and that  object can then be used to efficiently execute your insert statement multiple times.